# Call second function after first function fully completed in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function which is load help menu list (dropdown).

**First function**: *GetPageKeyword()*

```
function GetPageKeyword() {
    var url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, '').replace('/#', '').replace('#', '').replace('//', '/');
    url = url.split("?")[0];
    url = GetURL(url);
    if (url.lastIndexOf('/') == (url.length - 1))
        url = url.slice(0, -1);
    if (url.indexOf('/') == 0)
        url = url.substring(1, url.length);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/PageKeywords/GetLabelsByUrl",
        type: 'Get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { url: url },
        success: function (data) {
            var res = data.data;
            var htmlAppend = '<a id="hlpMenuLink" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>';
            if (res.length > 0) {
                $.getJSON("https://test.com/search.json?label_names=" + res[0].labels,
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.results.length > 0) {
                            htmlAppend += '<ul id="menuHelpUl" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">';
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                                htmlAppend += "<li><a href='" + data.results[i].html_url + "' target=\"_blank\">" + data.results[i].name + "</a></li>";
                            }
                            htmlAppend += "</ul>";
                        }
                        $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
                    });
            }
            $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);

            setTimeout(function () { GetArticulateDetails(); }, 1100);

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var err = jqXhr;
        }
    });
}
```

But now I need to add more item to help menu.
In the second function I tried to add the new item to ul id="menuHelpUl"  which I build in the first function.

**Second function**: *GetArticulateDetails()*

```
function GetArticulateDetails() {
    var url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, '').replace('/#', '').replace('#', '').replace('//', '/');
    url = url.split("?")[0];
    url = GetURL(url);
    if (url.lastIndexOf('/') == (url.length - 1))
        url = url.slice(0, -1);
    if (url.indexOf('/') == 0)
        url = url.substring(1, url.length);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/PageKeywords/GetArticulateLabelByUrl",
        type: 'Get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: { url: url },
        success: function (data) {
            var res = data.data;
            var htmlAppend = '<hr/>';
            if (res.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                     htmlAppend += "<li><a href='../HelpMenu/" + res[i].location + "/" + res[i].articulateIdentifier.trim() + "/index.html' target=\"_blank\">" + res[i].name + "</a></li>";
                }
            }
            $('#menuHelpUl').append(htmlAppend);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var err = jqXhr;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

In first function GetPageKeyword at last on success response, i am calling the second function which is

```
 setTimeout(function () { GetArticulateDetails(); }, 1100);
```

Here I am having problem some case the second function is not working because it may be it can not find id of #helpMenu.

code :  function : GetArticulateDetails :-- $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);

So there how I call my second funtion after compleate first function.

Comment: try implementing promises in javascript.

Comment: inside the success function

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI i already call my secound function  first success block  with set time out  setTimeout(function () { GetArticulateDetails(); }, 1100);

Comment: @js_noob  i dont know how to have promsie without ajax call

Comment: Any reason why you are not invoking the function within your callback?? See @dhilt answer, that's what you want

Comment: i did this on my code :  setTimeout(function () { GetArticulateDetails(); }, 1100); but problem is that this [ GetArticulateDetails()] run before my html genrate here [$('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);]  so after that i have to add this [GetArticulateDetails()] code in setTimeout function

Answer (score 1):

In your first method the call

```
$('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend)
```

Should be inside the handler for getJson(...)

Currently it is called before that method completes but relies on data generated by that async callback.

(I'd give you an explicit code change but difficult to edit on mobile)

Edit - actually the above line is duplicated. The one outside the handler can be removed. Perhaps there are duplicate Ids?

*You can also call the second method from within the getJson handler after the Html has been updated.*

menuHelpUl will only exist if the call in getJson returns some data. If it does not, there will be no element.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your second function right in the end of your ajax success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    /* settings */
    success: function (data) {
        var res = data.data;
        var htmlAppend = '<a id="hlpMenuLink" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>';
        if (res.length > 0) {
            $.getJSON("https://test.com/search.json?label_names=" + res[0].labels,
                function (data) {
                    if (data.results.length > 0) {
                        htmlAppend += '<ul id="menuHelpUl" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                            htmlAppend += "<li><a href='" + data.results[i].html_url + "' target=\"_blank\">" + data.results[i].name + "</a></li>";
                        }
                        htmlAppend += "</ul>";
                    }
                    $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
                    GetArticulateDetails(); // here !
                });
        }
        $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
    }
});
```

Also, maybe it would be necessary to protect this call by

```
if (data.results.length > 0) {
  GetArticulateDetails();
}
```

Comment: Was just about to reply with this, you beat me to it. :-)

Comment: i had done this before but not able ot get result to i modify code to set timeout   :- setTimeout(function () { GetArticulateDetails(); }, 1100); then it work but some case this timeout is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution using promises in javascript:

```
function GetPageKeyword() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        //your code here
        resolve();
    });
}

function GetArticulateDetails() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        //your code here
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
GetPageKeyword().then((result)=>{
    GetArticulateDetails();
}).catch((error)=>{
    //handle error
});
```

here is the edited first function :

```
function GetPageKeyword() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, '').replace('/#', '').replace('#', '').replace('//', '/');
        url = url.split("?")[0];
        url = GetURL(url);
        if (url.lastIndexOf('/') == (url.length - 1))
            url = url.slice(0, -1);
        if (url.indexOf('/') == 0)
            url = url.substring(1, url.length);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/PageKeywords/GetLabelsByUrl",
            type: 'Get',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: { url: url },
            success: function (data) {
                var res = data.data;
                var htmlAppend = '<a id="hlpMenuLink" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>';
                if (res.length > 0) {
                    $.getJSON("https://test.com/search.json?label_names=" + res[0].labels,
                        function (data) {
                            if (data.results.length > 0) {
                                htmlAppend += '<ul id="menuHelpUl" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">';
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                                    htmlAppend += "<li><a href='" + data.results[i].html_url + "' target=\"_blank\">" + data.results[i].name + "</a></li>";
                                }
                                htmlAppend += "</ul>";
                                $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
                                resolve()
                            }else{
                                $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
                                resolve()
                            }
                        });
                }else{
                    $('#helpMenu').html(htmlAppend);
                    resolve()   
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var err = jqXhr;
                reject()
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like OP is using ES6+

Comment: ok i can convert it to es5 but the concept of Promises are same in both ES versions.

Comment: It's pretty unnecessary though, he's using JQuery with callbacks. It's like cracking a nut with a sledge hammer :-D

Comment: but js is faster than JQuery :D

Comment: things are working file and calling functtion as your example in result got undefined that is not problem may be then called GetArticulateDetails

Comment: but  problem is   because in the first function when generating HTML before that my second function execute and try to find $('#menuHelpUl')

Comment: @AmitSinghRawat Yes i got the problem, i have modified the first function please try it out now, as you pointed out that result is undefined it is because while resolving we are not passing any parameter, that shd not be an issue, rest can u try with the modified first function and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

declare the menuHelpUl as a ui element like this:

```
var menuHelpUl = $('<ul id="menuHelpUl" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">');
```

and append li elements to it in loop

```
var li = $("<li><a href='" + data.results[i].html_url + "' target=\"_blank\">" + data.results[i].name + "</a></li>");
menuHelpUl .append(li);
```

now pass the menuHelpUl to GetArticulateDetails in ajax success:

```
GetArticulateDetails(menuHelpUl);
```

and use it in ajax success

```
menuHelpUl.append(htmlAppend);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the code it seems like **`$('#helpMenu')`** is found to be null or undefined.

try to check the **null** or **undefind** status of **`$('#helpMenu')`**

```
**if($('#helpMenu') == null || $('#helpMenu') == undefined)**
```

and then perform the append html operation.

Comment: yes are right it occred becase there is no element to get

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**jquery.when**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when(GetPageKeyword()).then(GetArticulateDetails());
```